# Static library gives strange errors on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, .a

I made a static library(.a) following the instructions of  Ray Wenderlich, compiled it without errors and warnings, and then I included it on a new project.  When I tried to build the new project, I got this error:

[image: error screenshot]

```
/Users/.../PruebaInsights/PruebaInsights/libInsightsLib.a:1:1: Source file is not valid UTF-8
/Users/.../PruebaInsights/PruebaInsights/libInsightsLib.a:1:5: Null character ignored
/Users/.../PruebaInsights/PruebaInsights/libInsightsLib.a:1:8: Expected identifier or '('
/Users/.../PruebaInsights/PruebaInsights/libInsightsLib.a:2:3: Invalid filename for line marker directive
/Users/.../PruebaInsights/PruebaInsights/libInsightsLib.a:3:10: Null character ignored
```

Why do I get these errors on the library, if I compiled correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely wrong:

```
#import "libInsightsLib.a"
```

`#import` is for importing header files, i.e. source-code declarations.  You are telling it to import a compiled binary library, and then the compiler is freaking out.

You need to use `#import` with the .h for whatever you're trying to use from that library.  The .a goes in the link phase of your app's build target.  Go back to Ray's tutorial, I'm sure it'll have those details.

Comment: Can you suggest how to import then?